# Error: memory limit exceeded when 17%-21% is used, according to psutils

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a Cloud Function with some intensive computing, using the following requirements:

```
requirements.txt 

google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-datastore 
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==0.24.2
scikit-image==0.16.1
psutil
memory-profiler==0.55.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
opencv-python==4.0.0.21
```

I have set the following arguments for deployment:

```
[--memory: "2147483648", --runtime: "python37", --timeout: "540", --trigger-http: "True", --verbosity: "debug"]
```

As the function iterates processing frames, the usage increases, but when reaching 18% - 21%, it stops with a:

> "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

Using psutils to make traces of the code, at the beginning of the call function I have this output (from the function's logs):

> "svmem(total=2147483648, available=1882365952, percent=12.3,
>   used=152969216, free=1882365952, active=221151232, inactive=43954176,
>   buffers=0, cached=112148480, shared=24240128, slab=0)"

This should mean, as for my understanding, that only 12.3% is being used at the beginning.
It makes sense, as the code packet itself (containing some binaries) plus the raw video chunks all together use 100MB, and I assume that all the installs from the requirements above may use an extra 160MB.

After about 15 iterations, this is the trace of psutil:

> svmem(total=2147483648, available=1684045824, percent=21.6,
>   used=351272960, free=1684045824, active=419463168, inactive=43962368,
>   buffers=0, cached=112164864, shared=24240128, slab=0)

Then, function is aborted.

This is the function where code stops:

```
    def capture_to_array(self, capture):
        """
        Function to convert OpenCV video capture to a list of
        numpy arrays for faster processing and analysis
        """

        # List of numpy arrays
        frame_list = []
        frame_list_hd = []
        i = 0
        pixels = 0
        # Iterate through each frame in the video
        while capture.isOpened():

            # Read the frame from the capture
            ret_frame, frame = capture.read()

            # If read successful, then append the retrieved numpy array to a python list
            if ret_frame:
                i += 1
                # Count the number of pixels
                height = frame.shape[1]
                width = frame.shape[0]
                pixels += height * width

                # Add the frame to the list if it belong to the random sampling list
                if i in self.random_sampler:
                    # Change color space to have only luminance
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:, :, 2]
                    # Resize the frame 
                    if frame.shape[0] != 1920:
                        frame_hd = cv2.resize(frame, (1920, 1080), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
                    else:
                        frame_hd = frame

                    frame_list_hd.append(frame_hd)

                    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (480, 270), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
                    frame_list.append(frame)
                    print('Frame size: {}, HD frame size: {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(frame), sys.getsizeof(frame_hd)), i)
                    print('Frame list size: {}, HD size: {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(frame_list), sys.getsizeof(frame_list_hd)), i)
                    print(psutil.virtual_memory())
            # Break the loop when frames cannot be taken from original
            else:
                break

        # Clean up memory
        capture.release()

        return np.array(frame_list), np.array(frame_list_hd), pixels, height, width
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Got it solved.
After this function the created frame lists are called within the following function:

```
def compute(self, frame_list, frame_list_hd, path, dimensions, pixels):
        """
        Function to compare lists of numpy arrays extracting their corresponding metrics.
        It basically takes the global original list of frames and the input frame_list
        of numpy arrrays to extract the metrics defined in the constructor.
        frame_pos establishes the index of the frames to be compared.
        It is optimized by means of the ThreadPoolExecutor of Python's concurrent package
        for better parallel performance.
        """

        # Dictionary of metrics
        rendition_metrics = {}
        # Position of the frame
        frame_pos = 0
        # List of frames to be processed
        frames_to_process = []

        # Iterate frame by frame and fill a list with their values
        # to be passed to the ThreadPoolExecutor. Stop when maximum
        # number of frames has been reached.

        frames_to_process = range(len(frame_list)-1)
        print('computing')
        # Execute computations in parallel using as many processors as possible
        # future_list is a dictionary storing all computed values from each thread
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
            # Compare the original asset against its renditions
            future_list = {executor.submit(self.compare_renditions_instant,
                                           i,
                                           frame_list,
                                           frame_list_hd,
                                           dimensions,
                                           pixels,
                                           path): i for i in frames_to_process}

        # Once all frames in frame_list have been iterated, we can retrieve their values
        for future in future_list:
            # Values are retrieved in a dict, as a result of the executor's process
            result_rendition_metrics, frame_pos = future.result()
            # The computed values at a given frame

            rendition_metrics[frame_pos] = result_rendition_metrics

        # Return the metrics for the currently processed rendition
        return rendition_metrics
```

Problem is, because of the ThreadPoolExecutor() was called with no arguments, it was using the default number of workers (5 times the number of available CPUs, which is 2). This was putting a number of frames too large for the memory, hence saturating my system.
Provided that each thread was outputting its own psutil data, I was being misled by my own traces.